# puppet provider run command as non root user

Tags: puppet

Is there a way to run commands as a specific user when writing a custom type/provider in puppet? I would like to avoid doing something like

```
commmands sudo: 'sudo'
sudo('-u', '<username>', '<command>','<options>')
```

At the moment I have a code block that looks like

```
commmands sudo: 'sudo'
def occ(options)
  sudo('-u','apache','php','occ',*options)
end
```

Would prefer not have to run the sudo command, but just run the php command.

Comment: Yes, but we need more code posted here to anser this question decently.

Comment: Updated question with more info.